# Adding additional information for referral links in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, referrer

I've been trying to do a bit of research into this but am not really able to find a proper answer.

I have a number of ad campaigns for my site and I want to see where referrals are coming from and which ad campaigns are working best.

For example, I want to tell how direct email marketing campaigns are performing compared to one another. Normally I think most of these come up as 'direct' traffic in Analytics.

However, I want to know if there is some way I can change the URL's in the various ad campaigns like:

```
example.com?adcampaign=1
example.com?adcampaign=2
example.com?adcampaign=3
etc,
```

And then be able to see these in Google Analytics as referrals like Google, Facebook etc,.

***Note:***
I am using Google Tag Manager to handle advanced ecommerce tracking in Analytics

Comment: I think this will answer your question: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en

Comment: @kgrg thanks this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference this is what is needed:

```
utm_source // the source it came from
utm_medium // the medium used
utm_campaign //the advertising campaign it is part of
```

ref: support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en